# Cardviews not showing after back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-cardview

I've successfully implemented [cardview and recycleview](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) in my navigation drawer. Now the problem is, when ever I clicked in my first cardview which will take me to my first fragment and then press **back**, my cardviews aren't in my list tab(1st fragment) anymore. The only option view the list of cardviews is to swipe to my navigation drawer again and click on the first fragment to view the cardviews.

here's my code for the
**RecyclerViewAdapter.class**

```
package com.example.guitarista.citem.Exhibitor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.guitarista.citem.Gallery_SpringForward.GalleryFragment;
import com.example.guitarista.citem.Gallery_activity.GalleryActivity;
import com.example.guitarista.citem.R;
import java.util.List;



/**
 * Created by smdojt on 1/24/2017.
 */

public class TabInt_RV_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TabInt_RV_Adapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        static CardView cv;
        TextView itemName;
        TextView itemCathegory;
        ImageView itemPhoto;

        ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            itemCathegory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_cathegory);
            itemPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo);
        }
    }

    List<Exhibitors_Int> items;
    Context context;
    TabInt_RV_Adapter(List<Exhibitors_Int> items, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_exhibitor_tabint_item, viewGroup, false);
        ItemViewHolder ivh = new ItemViewHolder(v);
        return ivh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, final int i) {
        itemViewHolder.cv.setOnClickListener(null);
        itemViewHolder.itemName.setText(items.get(i).name);
        itemViewHolder.itemCathegory.setText(items.get(i).cathegory);
        itemViewHolder.itemPhoto.setImageResource(items.get(i).photoId);

        ItemViewHolder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Index position is 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent (context, GalleryActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (i == 2) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Index position is 2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
                    GalleryFragment gf = new GalleryFragment();
                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, gf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


}
```

notice that on my onClick, there's two versions of gallery. The first one is the original activity, and the second one is implemented for fragment.

So when I clicked on the first one, and then back pressed, the cardviews will show. Now whats the problem with this? I cant swipe through navigation drawer when I click the activity version of gallery.

Where in, when I clicked on the second cardview which is fragment implemented, the navigation drawer swipe does work while inside the gallery, but when I press back, the lists of cardviews wont show.

even when I put these lines of code for fragment:

```
GalleryFragment fr = new GalleryFragment();
                     Bundle args = new Bundle();
                     fr.setArguments(args);
                     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
                     fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                     fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I'll just even get an error for **getFragmentManager();**

Is there any other way to solve this?

**CODE FOR CARDVIEWS**

```
package com.example.guitarista.citem.Exhibitor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.guitarista.citem.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TabInternationalFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<Exhibitors_Int> items;
    private RecyclerView rv;

    public TabInternationalFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exhibitor_tab_international, container, false);

        rv=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        //GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4);
        //rv.setLayoutManager(glm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
        return v;
    }

    private void initializeData() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Exhibitors_Int("A. GARCIA CRAFTS", "FURNITURE", R.drawable.image1));
        items.add(new Exhibitors_Int("BALEX BOXES", "HOLIDAY DECORATION", R.drawable.image2));
        items.add(new Exhibitors_Int("CAGAYAN DE ORO HANDMADE PAPER", "HOME DECOR/HOUSEWARE", R.drawable.image3));
    }

    private void initializeAdapter(){
        TabInt_RV_Adapter adapter = new TabInt_RV_Adapter(items, getContext());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: Post your fragment code here

Comment: The gallery fragment or the main fragment used in constructing these?

Comment: Yes, fragment in which you are showing card views

Comment: @Pehlaj added the fragment code for cardviews. its exactly the same with the tutorial that I posted.

Comment: Try calling initializeData();
        initializeAdapter(); in onResume method of fragment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your first activity as it was after you've pressed the back button, you should define the launch mode of your first activity in the AndroidManifest.xml. Also define the parent activity for your second activity, so Android knows which activity it should navigate back to when you press the back button.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.GalleryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
```

The singleTop launch mode will make sure that no new instance of that activity will be created if there is already an instance in the activity stack. So your cards will still be visible in your first activity after pressing the back button.